# PyCharm, Remote database connection through vpn

Tags: mysql, ssh, vpn, pycharm

I'm trying to connect to a remote database with SSH,
I'm using openvpn to connect to the network of the target machine.

This worked when I was directly connected to that network,
but it doesn't with VPN.

My settings are:

```
Database URL:
  jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306
(jdbc connector, user and password are OK)
```

SSH settings are:

```
Use SSH tunnel:
  (checked)
SSH tunnel will be opened on localhost (127.0.0.1) and port:
  32443 (tried with several other high ports)
Proxy host:
  192.168.100.143 (this is the address of the target machine in the target network I'm connected to through openvpn)
Port:
  22 (default)
(proxy user and auth are OK)

(not 100% sure about these two, are they relative to the above proxy host?)
Remote DB host:
  localhost
Port:
  3306
```

PyCharm tries to connect to localhost,
if I insert the mysql credentials for my localhost mysql server it connects to it (even though "use SSH Tunnel" is checked).

Am i missing something?

P.S.
The target database is MariaDB, but i don't think that's the problem since I could connect when directly connected to that network...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use this:

`jdbc:mysql://localhost:32443`

The point is to use the tunnel port.